# Calculating a function for each category of a variable (Loop function)

Tags: r

How can I calculate `sum(A$Freq)/sum(A$pi) (i=1,2,3)` for each level of `z` with the same index? I mean, when `z=regression1` we want to calculate `sum(A$Freq)/sum(A$p1)`, when `z=regression2` we need to calculate `sum(A$Freq)/sum(A$p2)`  and finally when `z=regression3` we need to calculate `sum(A$Freq)/sum(A$p3)`. Since my original dataset is very big and `z` has many levels, I am looking for a solution by using loop function.

```
Freq<-seq(100,126,1)
x<-seq(1,27,1)
z<-rep(c('Regression1','Regression2','Regression3'),each = 3, times=3)
p1<-seq(2,28,1)
p2<-seq(10,36,1)
p3<-seq(0,26,1)
s<-data.frame(x,Freq,z,p1,p2,p3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `sapply` function for the indices that you need to assess:

```
res <- sapply(1:3, 
    FUN=function(x) sum(s[grepl(x, s$z),"Freq"]) / sum(s[grepl(x, s$z),paste0("p",x)]))
res
[1] 9.166667 4.913043 7.250000
```

`grepl(x, s$z)` subsets rows of `s` to those that include the respective index.
`paste0("p",x)` creates the name of the column for the respective index.

Comment: Hi again. Can you provide a solution for this question too?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002416/combing-information-of-two-data-sets-loop-function/43002731?noredirect=1#comment73096601_43002731