# Combing information of two data sets_Loop function

Tags: r

I have two datasets: `m` and `s`. The first data set includes variables `Frequency`, `p1`, `p2` and `p3`.

The second dataset includes the value for *type of regression*, *mean* and *sample size*. Column names are `z`, `mean`, and `samplesize`, respectively.

I need to add four columns to the first dataset `m` as follows:

- The first column `m$reg1` should be `m$p1` times the value of `s$samplesize` corresponding to `s$z == 'Regression1'`.
- The second column `m$reg2` should be `m$p2` times the value of `s$samplesize` corresponding to `s$z == 'regression2'`.
- The third column `m$reg3` should be `m$p3` times the value of `s$samplesize` corresponding to `s$z == 'regression3'`.

I was wondering how can I write a loop function for calculating these new four columns in m data set.

See how the datasets are created in the code below:

```
Frequency<-seq(1,27,1)
p1<-seq(2,28,1)
p2<-seq(10,36,1)
p3<-seq(0,26,1)
m<-data.frame(Frequency,p1,p2,p3)

z<-c('Regression1','Regression2','Regression3','Regression4')
mean<-c(2,28,1,17)
samplesize<-c(10,20,30,40)
s<-data.frame(z,mean,samplesize)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same principle as we applied in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43000534/5967807). First, define names of columns or row values that would subset tables and then perform the calculation, filling the values into a new, similarly constructed, column.

```
# custom function that calculates column values 
add.col <- function(i){
    # name in the s$z that defines the correct row
    reg <- paste0("Regression", i)
    # name of the m column
    p <- paste0("p", i)
    # multiply the named column from m with respective samplesize in s
    return(m[, p] * s$samplesize[s$z == reg])
}

# loop through all indices
for(i in 1:3){
    # create a new column with the compound name and fill it with appropriate values
    m[, paste0("reg", i)] <- add.col(i = i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for a loop, if I understand your question correctly. Just do:

```
 m$regr1 <- m$p1*s$samplesize[s$z=="Regression1"]
 m$regr2 <- m$p2*s$samplesize[s$z=="Regression2"]
 m$regr3 <- m$p3*s$samplesize[s$z=="Regression3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a for loop this might work as well:

```
desired_col = c(2,3,4) # this can be any selection
```

`for(i in desired_col) { m[[paste0(i,"reg")]] = m[,i]*s[match(i,desired_col),3] }`

Comment: Hi. Thank for your reply. However I cannot use m[,i+1] because I have a large dataset and the columns are not successive. Can you modify your code?

Comment: Yes, the edited version takes any selection of columns and selects the first to last sample size values from `s` in a sequential order. The assumption is that the nr of cols match the nr of rows in `s`. You can also create a vector with desired_reg which selects the desired sample size for each iteration (e.g., `desired_reg = c("Regression1","Regression2")`